# how can i make it add reaction to the message

Tags: json, discord, discord.py

```
async def meme(ctx):
    content = get("https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme").text
    data = json.loads(content,)
    meme = discord.Embed(title=f"{data['title']}", Color = discord.Color.random()).set_image(url=f"{data['url']}")
    await ctx.reply(embed=meme)
    msg = await ctx.reply()
    await msg.add_reaction(reaction1)
    await msg.add_reaction(reaction2)
```

**um i was trying to make a meme command everything works fine idk why it doesnt add reaction to that message please help me get thru like i want it to react on the embed the bot just sent like on that message**

Comment: noone helped me  i helped myself it should be like this 
```async def meme(ctx):
    content = get("https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme").text
    data = json.loads(content,)
    meme = discord.Embed(title=f"{data['title']}", Color = discord.Color.random()).set_image(url=f"{data['url']}")
    msg = await ctx.reply(embed=meme)
    await msg.add_reaction(reaction1)
    await msg.add_reaction(reaction2)```

Comment: That's literally what my answer says

Answer (score 0):

You're not storing the right message

```py
    ...
    await ctx.reply(embed=meme)  # <- This is the message you send, put this in the variable instead
    msg = await ctx.reply()  # <- This will fail because it's empty, you're not sending any content
    ...
```